# Is it possible to just copy an existing TeXLive installation to a USB stick? (Windows)

Tags: windows

and if so, which files would I have to adjust?

Thanks

Comment: yes texlive installs everything under <somewhere>/texlive/2022 so you just need that directory and then set your path environment variable

Comment: Thank you. Where do I set that variable?

Comment: The "portable installation" option needs be set  when installing texlive. Then, everything goes into <somewhere>/texlive/2022.

Comment: Oh, then Alex you got me wrong. I don't wanna install it to the stick but copy it over and then use it. "Portable installation" takes at least 13 hrs according to the installer program.

Comment: No, I think I got you right. You first need a portable installation. You can have it on your computer and work with it as normal. But you can also copy it over to a  hot-pluggable memory device. A portable installation ensures that all settings, format files (which get regenerated quite often when important packages are updated) etc reside below <somewhere>/texlive/2022 and not somewhere else (eg the home directory on the host computer).

Comment: Oh ok. So I do a portable installation on <somewhere>\texlive-portable first an then just copy it? Shouldn't be too difficult. Thank you!